# Submit button on contact form not working

Tags: html, css

I had a few questions for site below
[www.haseebrahman.com](http://www.haseebrahman.com)

I wanted my headshot to be less narrow and a bit bigger.
In my "works" section I wanted the boxes to be a bit bigger, legible and wanted to be able to add four more boxes underneath. I'm not sure if the image on the home page is to smushed that's why it looks like that.
My contact us form isn't working. When users clicked submit, I wanted that information to be emailed.
Are there any thoughts/ideas you guys have to improve my site?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to form their questions in a manner that best enables the community to provide assistance.  Please note that [it is not generally considered acceptable to simply post a link to your offsite code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it); instead, you should strive to include a [mcve] _in_ your question body.  Also please note that posts should be narrow in scope.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: You need to add an 'action' to your form.

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: which backend language you are using..?

Comment: i dont hav eit right now

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your button type, like so:

```html
<button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: will this get emailed to me when some fills it out

Comment: For the submit button to submit the form, the button type needs to be defined as type="button". This will enable the button to submit the form. However, you still need some email logic and provider in order to sent out emails.

Comment: Yes what is the logic for the entire form?

Comment: I need more information to answer this question. E.g. what backend language are you using at the moment?

FYI - in my last comment I mentioned that the button type should be defined as "button", but I meant it should be defined as "submit". Like I stated in my initial answer.